# Bash Shell Script to get pattern match and fetch values in the line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a pattern like below in a file foo.txt

```
|eth0:9:8|eth1:7:0|
```

In a loop i have a variable with values eth0, eth1 and so on individually in Each iteration.

Based on the value of the variable, Say eth0 i need the values 9 and 8
In case of eth1 i need values 7 and 0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before posting a question, please refer to How to Ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: *In a loop i have a variable* - show your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The values you need are stored in `var1` an `var2` here.

```
TO_PARSE="|eth0:9:8|eth1:7:0|"
declare -a eths=(eth0 eth1)
for eth in "${eths[@]}"; do
  parsed=$(echo "${TO_PARSE}" | \
           awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; RS="|"}{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' | \
           grep "${eth}")
  var1=$(echo "${parsed}" | cut -f2 -d' ')
  var2=$(echo "${parsed}" | cut -f3 -d' ')
  echo "eth=${eth} var1=${var1} var2=${var2}" 
done
```